# Host port mapping not working with docker-compose on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I tried to run this [hello world](https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-hello-world) app on an AWS EC2 instance with `docker-compose up --build` . It works as expected and is accessible remotely from the EC2 public IP when I use port 80 i.e., "80:80" as shown in [the docker-compose file](https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-hello-world/blob/3dc906488e6ea479fcd383a8bd0bccaa634004a1/docker-compose.yml#L4).

However, if I change to another port such as "5106:80", it is not accessible from a remote host using `<public IPv4 address>:5106` even though it's available locally if I ssh unto the EC2 instance and try `localhost:5106`. Please note:

1. I've ensured the EC2 is in a public subnet and I have configured the security group to make the port (in this case, 5106) accept inbound traffic from my laptop.
2. I know it's not a problem with the hello-world app because I experience exactly the same problem with another app i.e., only port 80 works with docker-compose port mapping on EC2.

Comment: Would you post your inbound security group rules? It seems an issue with that. Make sure that the Source is `0.0.0.0/0` or your actual IP. Also, make sure that you are actually using the security group that your EC2 is in.

Comment: Yeah I've checked all that. That's why port 80 works but the new port doesn't.

Comment: I tried it with a fresh new EC2 machine and it worked. May it be an issue with your computer trying to connect to a port different than 80 or 443? Firewall or antivirus? Have you tried in any other device, like your phone or another computer?

Comment: @JuanScolari you last comment was the answer. Company firewall. Mind posting it as an answer so you can get the bounty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it works with port `80` and doesn't work with port `5106` it could mean one of two possibilities:

- There is an issue with your security groups. You should check you have added port `5106` in your `inbound rules` of your security group.
- There is an issue with a firewall or antivirus that doesn't allow you to connect to web pages in different ports rather than `80` or `443`. You may try if this happens with another device or on another network.

In this case, it seemed to be the latter.

Comment: Thanks! It was a firewall issue. I also found this amazing site that allows me to test the ports I can reach from within my company firewall. If the site shows on a port, it means that port is reachable on remote servers from within my network e.g., here're tests for port 80 (http://portquiz.net:80), port 443 (http://portquiz.net:443), and port 5106 (http://portquiz.net:5106).

Answer (score 2):

Possible that the docker network needs to be deleted?

`docker network rm $(docker network ls -q)`

Then run docker-compose up again.